# Multiple jboss hosting a domain and SSL

Tags: java, ssl, jboss

i have a need to have 2 jboss instances (horizontally clustered) both allowing SSL for the same domain. we were trying to figure out how to use one certificate to achieve this. is it possible to let each host have a keystore, and import the same SSL cert into each keystore? is that how it should be done?

in the past our network team has not been putting the ssl certs on the load balancers, so that is why this approach is preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured this out... i just copied the keystore from node1 to node2 and it worked fine. i only created the keystore once, on node1.